# PowerShell 1 is not capturing batch file output with tee

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0, tee

PowerShell can call commandline batch files. PowerShell script output can be recorded with the "tee" command. But the tee command does not record the output of batch files inside a PowerShell script for me in PowerShell 1.

Try this cut-down example:

Make a batch file, called **test.bat**, with contents

```
@echo hello from bat
```

Run it from PowerShell:

```
PS C:\> .\test.bat | tee out.txt
```

This works - You will have an output file, containing

```
hello from bat
```

Now make a PowerShell script called **test.ps1** that wraps the batch file, containing

```
write-output "hello from PS"
.\test.bat
```

Now run this with a tee:

```
 .\test.ps1 | tee pout.txt
```

This does not record the output of the batch files - the output file contains only

```
hello from PS
```

Whereas I expected

```
hello from PS
hello from bat
```

But no batch output is captured. How can I capture the output of this PowerShell script and subordinate batch files?

Comment: I added some stuff to my answer at the end. Why did you make this community wiki? Isn't that a disincentive for people to answer as they will not get points?

Comment: I made it a community wiki since last time I was on this site, people asked for that - the point being that they can edit it. The points difference isn't something that I know about, those rules may have changed in the meantime. Isn't that a secondary concern though? Is it something that I can change?

Comment: I don't really care about it; I was just curious. My understanding is that community wiki is for "opinion" questions that don't have black and white answers, especially for questions such as "What is your favorite programming language" that would generate a ridiculous amount of points. Any question can be edited, BTW, by people with sufficient points (2000 I think).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT:**

It appears to work in Powershell 2, but not in Powershell 1.

I found a work-around for Powershell 1 though. Try changing test.ps1 to this

```
write-output "hello from PS"
.\test.bat | write-output
```

Comment: I have updated for your comments - used "@" in batch file, made it clear that this is PowerShell 1

Comment: The workaround works for me too. We have a winner! 

So this must be something to do with the difference between write-console and write-output.